# Python mechanize login Facebook, use beautifulshoup get profile picture failed

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to keep login Facebook using Python mechanize library and get Zuck's profile picture url using BeautifulSoup. Here is my code:

```
import cookielib
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Enable cookie support for urllib2
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

# Broser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

#
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# authenticate
br.open('https://www.facebook.com/')
br.select_form(nr=0)
# these two come from the code you posted
# where you would normally put in your username and password
br['email'] = 'my_email_address'
br['pass'] = 'my_password'
res = br.submit()

print "Success!\n"

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck'
soup = BeautifulSoup(br.open(url).read())
# print soup
print [x for x in soup.findAll('img', {'class': 'profilePic img'})]
```

However, the html that BeautifulSoup read is not Zuck's Facebook homepage source code. The html starts with

```
<html lang="zh-Hans" id="facebook" class="no_js">...
```

It contains no 'img' with class = 'profilePic img' I need. What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: _“What's the problem?”_ – that you are trying to do something you are not supposed to – Facebook’s ToS forbid scraping without their explicit prior written permission. (And the fact that they load a lot of data via JS only.)

Comment: For sites that load a lot of data using Javascript, I used Selenium to load new pages.