# Python Requests Login Not Logging In

Tags: python, facebook-login

I am a beginner at the Requests module and am trying to login to facebook using the following code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1'
values = {'email': 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', 'pass': 'MYPASS'}
r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print(r.content)
```

However, when I examine the content of "r" after I post, the content are of the login page rather than my profile as I had hoped. So my question is, why is this script not logging in to my facebook profile? I apologize if I am making some simple mistake.

Comment: There are a bunch of hidden fields you would need to send along with it, associated with session cookies. So you have to request the login page, store the cookies for the next request, and pass the appropriate hidden field vaues. If this is just for experimenting with, you should probably try some other service; if you need to interact with Facebook, its API will probably work better.

Comment: So I would have to send the content of every other field alongside this data?

Comment: It is designed _specifically_ to be hard to use in this way.  This approach is notably against their terms of service, and can get you kicked off.

Comment: Okay, I was just starting out so I guess it might be better if I switch my testing site. Thank you for the information.

Comment: You may be interested in [a Python Facebook API](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Mechanize for this . there is a snippet that is used to login then its pretty easy to get links from that. Refer this [Python mechanize login Facebook, use beautifulshoup get profile picture failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898033/python-mechanize-login-facebook-use-beautifulshoup-get-profile-picture-failed) you will also come to know that scrapping the whole data will not be possible